# Маркированный список

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста

У меня в поле textarea вбивается текст примерно такого содержания

```
*Чебурашка
*Крокодил Гена
*Шапокляк
....
*нный элемент
```

Они разделены одним переносом

Мне нужно этот текст преобразовать в маркированный список:

```
<ul>
   <li>Чебурашка</li>
   <li>Крокодил Гена</li>
   <li>Шапокляк</li>
   ...
   <li>нный элемент</li>
</ul>
```

причем элементов может быть бесконечно

Пожалуйста, это единственное с чем я не справился

Такой механизм должен работать на js можно использовать jquery и на php

Буду очень благодарен

PS все знают Вики разметку, это аналогично

Звездочка означает элемент маркированного списка

Этот список может находиться где угодно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примере, я делаю вывод списка в div. Если надо будет отсылать данные на обработку (напр., записать в БД), то можно выводить список в скрытый textarea. [Посмотреть, как это работает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/E99Wy/2/)

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <textarea id="txt" name="txt" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
<div id="res"></div>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
var output = $('#res');
var txtArea = $('#txt');

function generateList(){

    var arr = txtArea.val().split('\n');
    var newStr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        newStr += '<li>' + arr[i] + '</li>';
    }
    output.html('<ul>' + newStr + '</ul>');
}

txtArea.keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.which == '0x0D'){
        generateList();
    }
});
```

**UPD#1**

Даже лучше [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/E99Wy/3/). Учитываем, если будет контент стираться/удаляться из textarea

**UPD#2**

Может не очень элегантное решение, но пока [вот такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/tUAxE/)

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли, это бы и я так смог бы сделать.
Мне нужно как в Вики разметке, этот текст может находиться где угодно.
Простите что не правильно указал идею

Comment: Но этот пример не удаляйте, он мне понадобится

Comment: Только сейчас добрался до компа... Фраза "текст может находиться где угодно" - не очень мне ясна. Пока в дополнении я сделал вариант так, как понял. Если не то что надо, то чуть подробнее объясните.

Answer (score 1):

Буду краток:

```
var text = "\n*Чебурашка\n*Крокодил*Гена\n*Шапокляк\n....\n*нный элемент";
var rtext = '<ul>' + text.replace(/\n\*([^\n]*)/g, '<li>$1</li>') + '</ul>';
```

Comment: Краткость сестра таланта)))

Answer (score 0):

сплитом текстэрию по "n", получаем массив, элементы добавляем форичем с помощью InnerText
n - символ каретки